# ScrollView for only part of a component? (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-ios

*(New to ReactNative)*

I currently have a React Native app which has a component with the following (rough) structure :

```
    <View>
      <View>
         <TextInput />
         <Text />
      </View>
      <View>
         <Image />
         <Button />
      </View>
    </View>
```

So within that parent View, let's call the children **View1** and **View2**. I can very easily substitute the parent View for ScrollView and have the whole component be scrollable. However, what if I want only **View2** to be scrollable and **View1** to stay in place? And I mean vertical scrolling, not horizontal scrolling/pagination.

How can I do this? Switching out **View2** for ScrollView does not work. I'm also looking for solutions where I wouldn't have to split those View1 and View2 into different components because there's a complex mechanism currently in place which relies on sharing state between the two.

Any suggestions? Happy to provide some of the actual code if necessary but I believe the above should be enough to get a feel for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using a nested component.

As you note, you can very easily have a whole component be scrollable. So by making View2 a separate component, you can implement the scrolling in View2 only.

From [http://reactjstutorial.net/](http://reactjstutorial.net/nested-components.html)

> Nested Components Nested Components are exactly what the name implies.
>   They are children nested inside parent components. They simply help us
>   create more complex UI structures. For example, an alert component
>   probably has another sub-component nested within it to indicate the
>   actual number of alerts. A message box has an inner input element and
>   a send button.

Comment: It's what I thought - but is it the only way? Like I said, I currently have a lot of state being shared between the children and it would be a bit of a hassle to restructure the whole thing. If it's the only way, then it's what I'll do, but I'm just exploring options.

Comment: Did you try placing a `ScrollView` inside View2?